# toggle two images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use someone's code from an earlier post that I posted on here, and in it, he provided a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9VvV/) that shows how to toggle between two images.

I'm trying to replicate exactly what that person is doing, but it doesn't seem to work on my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$('#ellomatey').toggle(
function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'bgimage.png');
},
function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'redsquare.png');
});​

</script>

</head>

<body>
<img id="ellomatey"  src="bgimage.png"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling that it's not calling the function correctly, but it seems to work on that person's example.

Comment: I think it would be great if you could create a list and then, remove the first add it to the last and keep on doing that as you might have more than 2 images still you will not have to change the code.so in javascript you would have an array.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers talk about the actual problem, but they don't tell you how you get to discover that, this is where debugging comes into play.

```
console.log("before");
$('#ellomatey').toggle(
function(){
    console.log("bgimage"); $(this).attr('src', 'bgimage.png');
},
function(){
    console.log("redsquare"); $(this).attr('src', 'redsquare.png');
});​
console.log("after");
```

If you do this, you'll notice "before" and "after" in your console. That's okay. But when clicking on the image, you would expect the other console logs, which means that the toggle function isn't doing what you thought it would do.

You can somewhat suppose the heavily used function to work properly, so there must be something up with the selector. Let's inspect that.

```
console.log($('#ellomatey'));
```

*Heh, what?! No elements.*

And then you start to think why and then you'll discover you need to wait till the DOM loaded; supposing you would have some underlying background in how a webpage loads, which is a prerequisite for what you're doing.

Wrapping

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

around it does exactly that.

*All it takes is a little understanding and some simple debug output...*

Don't just mindlessly code supposing it'll work, but verify your assumptions while you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a document.ready call. The way you have it the code will try to run before the actual content of the page has loaded.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ellomatey').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'bgimage.png');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'redsquare.png');
    });​
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your toggle function for an element that doesn't exist yet in the document, so you should wrap the js code on `window.load` handler (assuming you want to wait the complete image load) or at `document.ready` event

Answer (score 0):

I created a flexible toggle script:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/esukab/2/edit)*

put the *second image url* inside an `data` attribute for your image:

```
<img id="ellomatey"  src="img_1.jpg" data-src="img_2.jpg" />
```

and on click just call the 'swap' function!

```
$(function(){  // BTW, you were just missing this 'ready' function :)

   function swap(){
       var mem  = this.src;
       this.src = $(this).data('src');
       $(this).data('src',mem);
   }    
   $('#ellomatey').click( swap );

});
```

This snippet can also handle multiple elements by just nesting your elements:

```
 $('#ellomatey, .button, #something').click( swap );
```

(Added also in the demo a pure JS version. Have fun!)